# Add class to all elements with the same href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the href of a clicked anchor tag and add a class to all elements that has this same href?

I know how to add a class to one element but how do I add a class to all elements that has this same href?

```
$('.shop-item').on('click', function(e){
  var hrefz = $(this).attr('href'); //get the href on the clicked anchor tag
  var otherElem = $('a[href$='+hrefz+']').attr('href');
  alert(otherElem);
  //$(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

**EDIT:**

HTML (this is how the `href`s are)

```
<ul class="shop-list">
    <li class="shop-item"><a href="#Ordering"></a></li>
    <li class="shop-item"><a href="#Delivery"></a></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `addClass` on the collection that you selected:

```
$('a[href='+hrefz+']').addClass('newClass');
```

Note that `href$=` will select `href`s which *end* with the `hrefz` - if you want to select `href`s which *exactly match*, you should use `href=` instead.